# My cat is terrified of everyone other than me

Tags: cats, fear

I live with my family and we have had this cat, Tilly, for several years but she still seems to be terrified of everyone other than me (including my family). She is very comfortable around me but when anyone else comes near her, she runs off. How can I get her to be more comfortable with other people? Thanks for any advice you can give.

Comment: By "other people" do you mean strangers, or others that live in the house with you?

Comment: Both. She sometimes tolerates others in th family if she's especially relaxed and I'm there. She runs off at the first sight of strangers.

Answer (score 1):

Cats learn by action-reaction, or association. In other words, if something hurt or upset her and she was with a human, she may have assumed it was the human that caused it. She feels safe around you because she trusts you, but that doesn't remove that association in her mind about others. If she was a rescue, she may have been abused by humans previously. I had a cat who had a painful procedure by our male vet, causing her to hate men. You can't rewind the past or even know what caused it, but you can help her attempt to reassociate.

My first tip is to keep her indoors or within your yard (if you ever let her out). Who knows, you could have a neighbour who hates cats that you don't know about. My Nana used to throw ice at stray animals (I stopped that!) so you never know what could be happening when you aren't around.

Tell your family and people who come by frequently that you're trying to help her trust again. If they don't understand, try making a possible back story for her from before you got her that might explain the fear, and share it with them to help them understand what might have caused it. A little understanding goes a long way.

Have people walk softly and speak softly and positively when they're around her. Cats understand tone and she will instantly feel safer if people act nice and safe around her. This is important: if someone tries to interact with her and she hesitates or bolts, **do not be disappointed**! She will feel it and it will only make it harder. I know that's hard, but every little bit is progress!

Have friends and family sit at her level when they interact with her. When they look at her, make sure they don't open eye stare at her, because that's a sign of a threat for cats. Instead, have them slow blink at her when they look at her. When they go to interact with her, they should always offer a hand to sniff (palm up, middle finger lower than the others, arm outstretched). Let her sniff and choose the next move. Make sure they're patient, as she may take a few minutes to want to move forward more. When she does get closer, have them say "good job!" Softly, with a lot of over cheer in their voice. Give them treats to place in front of her when she gets closer (make sure they don't throw them at her).

Even with all that, she still may only warm up to the specific people that do this. That's okay though, she may have had a very strong association that will take a long time to break, if ever. Just keep up the slow blinks and encouragement!

One last thing, if you have someone else living with you, get them to give her her food dish (with you right beside them). That's a very good association for her!